# fnFilter not working for datatables and not clearing the values when refreshed

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am unable to clear the filters using the fnFilter().

Here is my HTML code :

```
<table id="todays _table>

               <thead>
                 <tr id="todays_search_input_feilds">
                     <td class="input_filter">
                        <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control search_events">
                    </td>
                    <td class="input_filter">
                        <input type="text" id="vendor " class="form-control search_events">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    </table>
```

And Here is my JQuery Code

```
$('#todays_table').dataTable().fnFilter('');
    oTable.fnClearTable();
```

I tried clearing using the following approach:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

But the problem with this is that, it is clearing the value but the data is not loading in the dataTable. It is loading only after i click on any of the filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#your_table').DataTable();
});

$('#id_btn').on('click', function(){
    table.search( '' ).columns().search( '' ).draw();
});
```